# How to prove $\gamma < \omega_1$?

Tags: ordinals

Let $\gamma=\sup\{\xi_n\}=\{\xi_n<\omega_1: n\in \omega\}$. How to prove $\gamma < \omega_1$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\gamma=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\xi_n$, it’s the union of countably many countable sets and is therefore countable; thus, it must be less than $\omega_1$.

Comment: @Brain, I might be wrong, but I think $\gamma$ is a number...

Comment: @Easy: $\gamma$ is an ordinal number, which means that it is the set of smaller ordinals.

Comment: IMO, it is important in these foundational set-theoretic settings to indicate use of choice principles; you used some form of countable choice.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: This isn’t particularly foundational, and in any case everything in sight is well-ordered, so no choice is required. (Besides, my default set theory is ZFC unless AC is *explicitly* an issue.)

Comment: It does not matter that everything is well-ordered. One still has to choose bijections $\xi_n \to \Bbb N$ for each $n$. Both Wikipedia and T.Jech (in _Set Theory_) agree that some choice principle is necessary to show $\aleph_1$ is regular.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: The Wikipedia comment doesn’t actually say that some choice is necessary — it just says that AC is sufficient — but, yes, you’re right: it is consistent that $\operatorname{cf}\omega_1=\omega$, so some small amount of choice is used. (It’s been a long day, and I’m apparently starting to fade.) However, in the present context I really don’t think that this needed to be mentioned; Paul’s mostly doing topology, and in that setting the dependence on some choice is more curiosity than important observation.